Number of non-isomorphic graphs with $3$ or fewer vertices
I am asked to show that "there are $8$ non-isomorphic graphs with $\leq3$ vertices.
I count $4$ with $3$ vertices, $2$ with $2$ vertices and $1$ with $1$ vertex. Is the $8$-th graph, the empty graph?
Thanks in advance

Since you've counted the other sizes correctly, I believe so.

An "empty graph" is a graph with no edges. The "graph" with no vertices is called the null graph.
